# Which complex numbers work as a (numeral) base?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

When we write a real number in base k the n’th digit represents the number of k^n. I’m interested in finding a complex number w such that any complex number z can be written in base w.

I found that w=ai where a is whole doesn’t work because the number of i’s of any number represented in this bad will be divisible by a.

Just to be clear: We can only use digits that are smaller then the absolute value of the base. For example, if the base is 1+i , we can only use 0,1 as the digits ( 1<|1+i|=sqrt(2)<2 ).

Comment: It does, but only if you can use the digits 0,1,2 and 3. However, |2i|=2, so for my question you could only use 0 and 1. This doesn’t work.